# Chat App with Xamarin on a Linux server?

Tags: linux, xamarin.forms, signalr

I've been searching through forums and blogs, and am having a hard time finding anything concrete. My question is simply: how can I create a chat component in my Xamarin Forms app using a Linux/Apache server? I don't have a budget, which makes an efficient solution tricky. I see that SignalR is the way to go in the ASP.NET realm, but I'm not sure how doable it would be on a Linux server. (My hands are tied).

Any good SignalR alternatives for a Linux server these days that I can plug into Xamarin? Or is there a different route I should look for all together?

Thanks for any leads!

Comment: https://xmpp.org/software/servers.html

Comment: Thanks! Good lead. Digging around more, it seems like getting the different XMPP libraries to work on Xamarin is a headache. Are there any successful apps/examples out there that use any of these libraries in Xamarin? I'm using PCL, but can switch at this point if I need to. I'm also hoping to use Openfire as my XMPP server.